# BlueStacks adds trailing space when paste text from clipboard

Tags: bluestacks

I have an issue with BlueStacks4 clipboard

When I copy text from host Windows 10 it adds trailing space for each line when I paste it in the BlueStacks

```
line1
line2
line3
```

pasted as

```
line1_
line2_
line3
```

Here `_` is a space character.

Is theere a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> When I copy text from a Windows 10 host, it adds trailing spaces for each line when I paste it into BlueStacks.

Windows uses [*Carriage Return + Line Feed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Issues_with_different_newline_formats) (`CRLF` or `\r\n`) to denote line endings. In contrast, *Nix derived operating  systems (such as Android, which BlueStacks runs) often simply use *Line Feed* (`LF` or `\n`).

It sounds like something is translating/representing `CR` in `CRLF` as `Space` instead (or some visual equivalent). This is less likely to be Windows and more likely to be either BlueStacks or perhaps even the text editor you are using in BlueStacks.

> Is there a way to fix this?

Barring settings changes of some kind in BlueStacks or simply trying different editors in Android, the most direct approach might be to use another script or program on Windows (e.g. [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) to convert your `CRLF` line endings into `LF` line endings before pasting into BlueStacks.

Comment: thanks, but switch to LF did not work. I tried different editors on BlueStacks but the issue persists. I think it is BlueStacks issue. Asked the tech support